# access storyboard and nested UIViewControllers in appDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, uistoryboard

How can I access storyboard as well as it's UIViewControllers inside the appDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: it's for reasons that maybe out of scope of strategies out there but mainly the purpose is to hook PureMVC framework, and instantiate mediators to ViewControllers (inside storyboard) inside AppDelegate or maybe inside another class launched from AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case your UIViewController is named MyViewController and its storyboard has name MyViewController.storyboard, the code you've requested will look like this:

```
// load storybord with name MyViewController.storyboard
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

// get an instance of root view controller for the storyboard
MyViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, suppose there are 3 or more UIViewController inside the storyboard, how can I access each of them? (I hope they are instantiated already by the iOS, NO?)

Comment: You are able to instantiate any UIViewController added to the storyboard using it's identifier. The identifier is a basic string that you should specify in Identity inspector tab of Interface Builder side menu for selected view controller, by default whatever view controller you've added to the storyboard have no identifier string.
Instead of <instantiateInitialViewController> you should use <instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:> and pass the identifier as a parameter to get an instance of concrete view controller from the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *uvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:uvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks Suny, I've added some comments to the above answer, basically trying to access all UIViewControllers inside the storyboard